# How does one build android kernel from sources on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, android, compiling

I am trying to build Android from sources on Ubuntu 13.04, yet there are numerous issues:

1. Setting up the environment issues (wrong tool chains)
2. Compilation/Build errors

Comment: It's OK now, but you could edit your original question instead of deleting. I think I lose my vote.

Comment: I deleted the post in order to avoid duplication. I'm somewhat new to StackExchange. What does "losing your vote" mean? Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

Comment: Ah, don't care about it. It doesn't hurt. Just wish to tell you about your abilities. Anyway, you somehow reached 200 points on StackOverflow, so you probably must know how StackExchange works and what is voting. And thanks for your wish to fixing it :)

Comment: I know how it works to that extent. I don't understand the concept of losing a vote. Can't you re-vote?

Comment: But.. thank you for the suggestion to move to Q&A.

Comment: I already did it. The only thing I can't do is to revoke my vote to your previous question, but since you deleted it, this operation does not make sence. And tomorrow my votes will be recovered, so, as I said, do not care about it. I never had reached 30-votes-per-day limit yet :) Just relax and gain your points ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having spent an entire day setting up the environment and building Android from its sources; I want to share the useful information that I found floating around.

My system is an Asus S56C (i7-3537U) with 4GB RAM. I downloaded the master branch, which at this time is `android-4.0.1_r1`

The first thing to do, is to set up the environment. This is clearly explained in [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). There are three things to pay attention to:

1. While [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) gives the option of using make 3.81 - 3.82, the build will fail if you don't have 3.81 set. Therefore, this is the one you should use.
2. I initially installed openjdk-6-jre, however this was the wrong version of the jre. Following [this link](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-678-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/), I installed `oracle-java6-installer` instead
3. There is a typo on the section about [configuring the ccache](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#ccache). It should read `prebuilt/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 50G`

The following is a list of links form which I derived the changes to the source/make files that'll follow.

1. [[GUIDE] Building CyanogenMod 9 from Source with openSuSE 12.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1980379).
2. [Fix for Dalvik compile error on CyanogenMod 9](http://mjanja.co.ke/2013/04/fix-for-dalvik-compile-error-on-cyanogenmod-9/)
3. [Debian Bug report logs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673266)
4. [lenario bug report](http://review.android.git.linaro.org/#/c/2359/)
5. [Building Android 4.0.4 (Master branch) on Arch Linux 64-bit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/3NeP47-cYdg/11Rwfz5kM5QJ)

As a result, the following changes were made:

1. On line 31 of `frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Android.mk`, add `-fpermissive`

   ```
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-format-y2k -fpermissive
   ```
2. On line 64 of `frameworks/base/libs/utils/Android.mk`, add `-fpermissive`

   ```
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLIBUTILS_NATIVE=1 $(TOOL_CFLAGS) -fpermissive
   ```
3. On line 183 of `frameworks/base/libs/rs/Android.mk`, add `-fpermissive`

   ```
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -fpermissive
   ```
4. On line 22 of `frameworks/compile/slang/Android.mk`, remove `-Werror`

   ```
   local_cflags_for_slang := -Wno-sign-promo -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter
   ```
5. On line 125 of `frameworks/compile/linkloader/Android.mk`, replace `LOCAL_LDFLAGS with LOCAL_LDLIBS`

   ```
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
     -lpthread \
     -ldl
   ```
6. On line 94 of `external/oprofile/libpp/format_output.h`, remove the specifier `mutable`
7. on line 41 of `external/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h`, after `#include <vector>`, add `#include <stddef.h>`
8. On lines 52 and 71 of `external/gtest/src/Android.mk`, add `-fpermissive`

   ```
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O0 -fpermissive 
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O0 -fpermissive
   ```
9. On line 25 of `development/tools/emulator/opengl/Android.mk`, add `-fpermissive`

   ```
   EMUGL_COMMON_CFLAGS := -DWITH_GLES2 -fpermissive
   ```
10. After line 7 of `development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/renderer/Android.mk`, add new line

    ```
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lX11
    ```

I hope that this makes your life easier when building Android.